# Is Await inside a Promise ignored?

Tags: javascript, promise, google-cloud-firestore, es6-promise

I have this simple function below, where you  would pass in a String as parameter which would return a Promise that would only resolve to either empty object or filled object, based on a firestore sub-collection query.

The problem is the very last `resolve({})` is called even if I've invoked an await on the previous statement, what could possibly be happening?

```
getSubCollections = (id: string): Promise<any> => {
    const subCollectionPromise = new Promise(async (resolve: Function) => {
      if (typeof this.subCollectionKeys === 'undefined') {
        resolve({});
      }

      const collections = {};

      await this.subCollectionKeys.forEach(async (key: string) => {
        const subCollection = await this.getCollection()
          .doc(id)
          .collection(key)
          .get();
        const firebaseObj = await subCollection.docs.map((obj: Object) =>
          this.getShallowData(obj),
        );
        const fromFirebase = fromFirebaseObj(firebaseObj);

        if (!fromFirebase.empty) {
          collections[key] = fromFirebase;
        }
        resolve(collections);
      });

     resolve({}); /// WHY IS THIS CALLED EVEN IF THERE IS AWAIT ON TOP???
    });

    return subCollectionPromise;
  };
```

Comment: You can't `await` a `forEach` because `forEach` does not return a `Promise`.

Comment: Suggestion, instead of `forEach` do a `.map` and return the promise array of the callback so you can do `await Promise.all(this.subCollectionKeys.map(...)`

Comment: `await` only "waits" if the value you are awaiting is a promise that resolves only when your async operation is done.  That is not the case with `this.subCollectionKeys.forEach()` so there's nothing to actually `await`.  If you use a `for` loop instead of `.forEach()`, you can `await` each async operation inside the loop and the whole loop will pause for each one.  You're also calling `resolve(collections)` inside a loop which is misleading code at best, wrong code at worst.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, I've managed to make it work by `.map`. I didn't know before that it wouldn't wait non-promise statements.